# What is the opposite of an exhaustive list?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

In Japanese, the particle と is used within an exhaustive list of items, to separate each item. E.g.

> りんご**と**バナナ**と**メロンがあります。 (Ringo to banana to meron ga arimasu.)
>
> I have an apple, a banana, and a melon. (implication: I have nothing else.)

The particle や is used to list items in a way that suggests that you have other things, but there's no point in listing them all, similar to how we use "etc.":

> りんご**や**バナナ**や**メロンがあります。 (Ringo ya banana ya meron ga arimasu.)
>
> I have an apple, a banana, a melon, etc. (implication: I also have other things.)

What type of listing would the second example be? In other words, what is the opposite of an exhaustive list?

Comment: A single item, perhaps?

Comment: Well, that would defeat the point of a list.

Comment: non-exhaustive?

Comment: Are you asking for a term to describe an list that is not exhaustive, or for English punctuation for the two kinds?

Comment: I'm looking for the former.

Comment: "I have a variety of items including but not limited to: a apple, a banana, and a melon". That's how you sometimes see it phrased in legal contracts.

Comment: About all I can think of is "partial list", and that is implied (and therefore need not be explicitly stated) if the list ends with "etc".

Comment: Similar to what @A E stated, but less formally, simply using "including" sufficiently implies that the list is not complete: "I have many foods, including a banana and a melon".\

Comment: *et cetera* should only be used when it is obvious how the list continues; it cannot be used for an arbitrarily trimmed list, like "I have an apple, a pen, a ball, {* *et cetera* | and some other things}" because we cannot guess what follows.

Comment: I've heard people describe a list as abbreviated.

Comment: @Kaz, I would've said et al. fulfils that function. You don't need to guess what follows etc, its purpose is to vaguely gesticulate at "such things".

Comment: [offtopic] The japanese particle ya does not indicate strictly a non-exhaustive list. It behaves in some ways as a conjunction, and also as a disjunction, not unlike some uses of the English "or". For instance, the equivalent of "have some tea or coffee" can expressed with "ya"; "kohii ya o cha do'zo". It doesn't mean you should have coffee and tea, plus possibly some other unspecified drinks! The word "nado" emphasizes that examples are given: "enpitsu nado" (pencils and such) "enpitsu ya pen nado" (pencils, pens and such). "enpitsu ya pen ga aru no?" (Do you have a pencil *or* pen?)

Comment: @Leo _Et al._ refers to people (or locations in texts), not just any random things. I disagree that the rest of the list must be inferrable for _et cetera_ to work, though. There are just certain expectations to the context in which a list is expressed for it to work: “I have an apple, a pear, an orange, etc.” doesn't work either, even though the list can be inferred; but “The room was a mess—full of scraps of paper, food, bags, tea towels, etc.” does, even though we can't infer what comes after.

Comment: It occurs to me that the opposite of an exhaustive list should be a restful one.

Comment: @Janus, yes, I was saying etc. Is for a non-inferrable list and et al. is for a known/inferrable list.

Comment: @Hot Licks +1, but that would be the opposite of an exhaust*ing* list :)

Comment: @LeoKing I don’t think inferrability is really all that relevant for either—context, not inferrability, decides whether or not it works. That bit of it was mostly in reply to Kaz’ post, though; my point about _et al._ was just that it’s only used for _people_, not things. “I have an apple, a chair, a balloon, et al.” makes absolutely no sense to me, unless the apple, chair, and balloon are all strange ways of referring to people.

Comment: @HotLicks Or more literally, an [_inhaustive_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inhaust) one. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Maybe it should be an *intakive* list.

Comment: So basically, we're calling it fat?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think your "mess" example works because we don't really care what _etc._ specifically stands for in that context.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to simply state the list is incomplete, you can say a "***partial*** list"; if you want to emphasize the list is *intentionally* not exhaustive, you can say a "***selective*** list". If you're simply listing *some examples*, you can say that.

The English (well, ok, Latin) typographic convention which corresponds to your "*と*" is "***i.e.***": *that is*, *specifically*, *exactly*, and respectively to "*や*" is "***e.g.***": *for example*.

Comment: You are correct to suggest this and I wish I could give you more than one + for it.  However, I would like to point out, that in my experience, it is somewhat uncommon for people to be aware of the distinction between i.e. and e.g.

Comment: I'd like to disagree with your last point but I suspect you're right

Comment: I certainly do, i.e. its clear to me and useful in many cases, e.g. questions that include an example

Answer (score 17):

You could say an

> Incomplete list

is not exhaustive. However note that neither this, nor the "*partial list*" of [the previous answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/207968/), is truly an antonym: they imply that there definitely are other items which our presented list does *not* include, but which an *exhaustive* list would.

To include the possibility that our list *could potentially* be *exhaustive*, but we don't have enough information to say that definitively, I'd still go with a

> Non-exhaustive list

Comment: It's good practice not to repeat answers already given by others.

Comment: I wasn't aware answers were required to be so discrete.

Comment: @DanBron: I vehemently disagree that blgt is required to post an incomplete answer just because you have already posted part of what he wants to say.

Answer (score 6):

Being a mathematician at heart, I would use “a sample” or “a sampling”
(as used in statistics), or “a subset” (from set theory). 
Strictly speaking, neither of these is explicitly non-exhaustive
(at least in set theory, any set is a subset of itself,
so “subset” *could* refer to the entire collection),
but they have the connotation of representing less than the whole.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a list that you want to later add something to, aware that it is incomplete, you could call it a *[tentative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tentative)* list.

Equally suggesting that the incompleteness is a known factor, but implying one should work off of the list until further items are added, is a *[provisional](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/provisional)* list.

Both words imply that the list is known to be incomplete, and that more items may be added in the future, but that the items included are a rough guide to follow until or unless revisions are made to that list.

Also note that in certian cases, these terms can mean incomplete in the sense that items might be *removed* from the list, such as picking players for a sports team and eliminating them as the list is changed.  And both of these terms can become a complete list if later one decides that the list no longer needs modification, but that it can still mean a list that is incomplete, and in the context of lists where items might be added later, the meaning would be understood.

Comment: Tentative and provisional do not imply incomplete. They only imply that the list may change. Items could be added, removed, substituted, or the list may remain unmodified.

Comment: @NoahSpurrier It still implies the list is incomplete, or based on what is known to be necessary so far. Assuming the user's intent is to indicate that the list has not yet been finished. You are right to say that sometimes items may be *removed* from the list, but it is much more common that the 'tentative' or 'provisional' nature of a list indicates items that are known to be needed, in the case of getting grocery items as an example (though in cases like picking people for a sports team, you are right that items might be removed).

Answer (score 2):

I would say an **indicative list**.

In french we use the expression "A titre indicatif" to precise that something (an information, a list,...) is not exhaustive and is provided solely for guidance and should neither be quoted nor considered as having legal value.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of *exhaustive* in the sense of "testing all possibilities or considering all elements: THOROUGH" (the definition in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary) might be *scattershot*. Again from the Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary:

> **scattershot** *adj* (1951) broadly and often randomly inclusive : SHOTGUN {*scattershot* advice} {*scattershot* planning}

A "scattershot list" would thus be a list that draws elements from across a large underlying population but does so without any attempt at exhaustiveness or even systematic representation.

Comment: +1 for a nice word, if obscure :)

Answer (score 0):

Would **cursory list** fit the situation?

Comment: Are you asking a question, or providing an answer? (I'd suggest quoting a couple places where this expression is used, to bolster the answer. As it stands now, it almost looks like you lengthened a two-word suggestion into a question just to meet the character minimum.)

Comment: Regardless, this seems more suitable as a comment.

Comment: @Leo - In its current form, perhaps. But _cursory list_ is a good option; it's an [oft-used phrase](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+cursory+list%22) that fits the O.P.'s bill. Rather than saying, "This should be a comment," I'd prefer to say, "Let's make this better; it's a good suggestion."

Comment: Good point, nice attitude.

Answer (score 0):

Just an 'open list' if it has not been finished.

Comment: Hi B_witam, welcome to ELU! Could you give a bit more detail in your answer, please! [We tend to delete answers that are very short and don't explain why they might be right or might be helpful...]

Answer (score 0):

As a Japanese, I would use "complete, or definate" list for conjunction, と,　and "incomplete / indefinite, or open" list for や for explaining the functions of と and や on the list of items.

P.S. 
Perhaps you can get more pertinent answers from Japanese Language site of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

I would immediately use *inclusive list*; the list includes these items, but could include others too.