# Name for inexhaustive "or", which doesn't cover all the cases?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there a name for a use of "or" that doesn't cover all the cases, such as

```
We could go to the beach, or go climbing ...
```

Where there are more activities than are listed.

Comment: I know Japanese has a distinction between exhaustive "and" と and inexhaustive "and" や but I don't think there's a special name for it when it's inexhaustive (the latter just gets called the incomplete list marker).

Comment: Your example *does* cover all the cases.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I wasn't sure how to communicate that there were more choices available without listing them in the example.  Hmm...

Comment: Just let your sentence trail off into nothing, by ending with ellipsis.  "X, or Y, or. . ."

Comment: Related (and maybe a dupe), also from someone with a Japanese background: [What's the opposite of a exhaustive list?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207967/what-is-the-opposite-of-an-exhaustive-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call it an **open-ended list**.